# R keeps prompting to restart for installation

Tags: r

I keep receiving this prompt when installing R packages. When I hit "Yes", it just repeats itself. It turns off, then reopens with the same prompt. I've exited out of R and it did not work. What is this prompt asking?
[image]

Comment: Usually means you already have them installed. check your packages folder if they are already installed.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi as i already said... i restarted it

Comment: Clear your environment, remove *.rdata files from the folder, then if nothing else work delete the hidden ".Rproj" folder. After each step try restarting and reinstalling until it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this means that you already have that package installed. Stop executing that line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Restart RStudio or run `install.packages()` in R CLI or R GUI.

As the other answer stated, it might mean that you already have the package installed.
Regardless if that holds or not, `install.packages()` should install the latest version of the package, i.e. also *update* it if necessary.

As explained in [this answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/restart-r-session/83030), an update can fail if the package you are trying to update is already loaded.
In many cases, simply restarting R session is sufficient to unload the package, which can then be updated without any problems.
In your case, this did not help as evidenced by the prompt occurring over and over again.

To solve this problem, you can first try to restart RStudio (and not just your R session).
If that does not help, avoid using RStudio at all (which might load some packages automatically): run R from the command line or R GUI (bundled with R) and update the packages in a completely clean session.
As stated in the answer linked above, also "make sure you are not loading any packages through a start-up file (`Rprofile.site` or `.Rprofile`)".

Answer (score 0):

Use Revo Uninstaller to uninstall both R and RStudio and reinstall them. It worked for me.